# ImageView height too large in recyclerview with use of StaggeredGridLayoutManager [Android/Kotlin]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, kotlin, staggered-gridview

It Working in fine in old project **which is written in java**

When same things written in **kotlin** its not working...

Problem RecyclerView Item **Height Too Large**

```
lateinit var mImageProcessedRecyclerViewAdapater:ImageProcessedRecyclerViewAdapater
lateinit var mImageContainerAfterProcess: RecyclerView
```

//initializing adapter and itemdecoration

```
    mImageContainerAfterProcess= findViewById(R.id.ImageContainerAfterProcess)

    mImageContainerAfterProcess.addItemDecoration(RecyclerViewItemDecoration(16))

    mImageContainerAfterProcess.layoutManager=StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)

    mImageContainerAfterProcess.adapter=mImageProcessedRecyclerViewAdapater
```

> item view xml file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/processedImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Activity Layout File which contains recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activitis.ImageProcess">

    // layout height and width is match_constraint 
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ImageContainerAfterProcess"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/processd_image_item_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**i cant find out what i am doing wrong**

**output capture via layout inspector**

[image]

**My Old Project output**

[image]

Comment: post your recyclerview  xml full code

Comment: @sasikumar posted

Comment: both of the ConstraintLayouts are unnecessary because RecyclerView as well as ImageView are only child of its parent. They can be root element. Also, try to fix RecyclerView width and height as match_parent and put ImageView's width as match_parent. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @RahulKumar thanks for your comment sir but its not working

Answer (score 3):

Try to adding this to your processedImage `ImageView`.

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
//use centerCrop to fill staggered view or centerInside to avoid cropping.
```

Comment: Thank you with these property image view got the perfect height as required.

Answer (score 0):

`wrap_content` does not behave in a similar way with constraint layout. To achieve what you want you will need to add below code to your `ImageView` and set its width and height to `0dp`

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

Comment: did you set height and width of imageview to 0dp?

Comment: set it to 0dp and try.

Comment: any other suggestions sir ?

Comment: is your image too large, can you check the dimensions from source image?

Comment: yes image was too large but this code is working on old project i will past the output

Comment: are you using glide to load image?

Comment: If using constraint layout is of not importance, try using linear or relative layourt.

Comment: both tried linearlayout and relative layout as parent of imageview

Comment: did you clean and build after changing?

Comment: yes i clean the project and run again gots same output

Comment: let me tell one thing after getting bitmap i will modify the bitmap just writing some text on it, i am not changing the height width of bitmap then showing in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

your image view should be like this

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/processedImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: can you set  imageview height as  android:layout_height="200dp"

Comment: if we want to fix the height of image then why we use StaggeredGridLayoutManager sir

Answer (score 0):

My Out put is
[image]

```
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

All Code is Here
Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_preview"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

and Code is

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
    layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```